# mutiple lines in single line and remove duplicates from some lines

Tags: bash, shell, sequence, lines

Here is what I have and this is the entire sequence :

```
aa="aa1"
etime="1436262792"
from="joe"
test="blah"
test="blah1"
test="blah2"
addr="aa2";
aa="aa1"
etime="1436262792"
from="bob"
test="blah3"
addr="aa2";
etc...
```

sometime the test line is limited to one, however each separated with ";".
When there is multiple "test", I need to keep only the last one.

I am trying to get this results:

```
aa="aa1" etime="1436262792" from="joe" test="blah2" addr="aa2";
aa="aa1" etime="1436262793" from="bob" test="blah3" addr="aa2";
```

Here is my current findings;

```
cat file | xargs | tr ';' '\n;'
```

the output look like this :

```
aa="aa1" etime="1436262793" from="joe" test="blah" test="blah2" test="blah3" addr="aa2"
aa="aa1" etime="1436262793" from="bob" test="blah3" test="blah3" addr="aa2"
```

Thank you for any suggestions,

Al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sed

```
sed '/test/h;//!{x;//p;x;h};${//p};//d' file
```

Holds test lines in buffer, overwriting the previous till there isn't one and deletes the line.

At the next none test line or end of the file it prints the last test, given that one is saved.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep track of the last line starting by `test` that appeared and print it when a line does not start like that:

```
$ awk '/^test/ {t=$0; next} {if (t) print t; print; t=""}' file
aa="aa1"
etime="1436262792"
from="joe"
test="blah2"
addr="aa2";
aa="aa1"
etime="1436262792"
from="bob"
test="blah3"
addr="aa2";
```

Then pipe to `xargs -n 5` to print on blocks of 5 fields per line:

```
$ awk '/^test/ {t=$0; next} {if (t) print t; print; t=""}' file | xargs -n 5
aa=aa1 etime=1436262792 from=joe test=blah2 addr=aa2;
aa=aa1 etime=1436262792 from=bob test=blah3 addr=aa2
```

Comment: This won't capture ones at the end of the file.

Comment: It is not the case in the input data. However, if it was, an `END {if (t) print t}` would make.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this alternatively...count the amount of word per line...

```
    while read line;
    do
    COUNT=$(echo "${line}" | wc -w)

    if [ "${COUNT}" == "7" ]
    then
    echo ${line} | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$6,$7}' >> tmp8
    elif [ "${COUNT}" == "6" ]
    then
    echo ${line} | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6}' >> tmp8
    else
    echo ${line} | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' >> tmp8
    fi
    done < tmp7
```

Comment: this is a quite long way to do something tha `awk` would handle in a quite straight forward way: `awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $(NF-1), $NF}'`